# Recording audio returned by an URL

Tags: java, url, audio, javasound

I have an URL that returns Audio (along with some small amount of text). How can I record this audio using Java?

I attempted using URL and BufferedReader class but BufferedReader returned only texts.

```
URL audioURL = new URL("http://goo.gl/O8bi6");
```

This is a BBC Nepali Radio service uri. I would like to record it for personal use. I've tried, as pointed by `jason-sperske` using `ByteArrayOutputStream` , `FileOutputStream`. Still no luck.

How do I differentiate between audio content and texts from binary data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=245 BufferedInputStream handles the buffering of what is read, it can be binary data

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873179/copy-binary-data-from-url-to-file-in-java-without-intermediate-copy this could help as well

Comment: This seems to be exactly what you looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/568616/reading-strings-and-binary-from-the-same-stream

Comment: If you expand your question to include some details like the structure of the data at the URL I'm sure someone will write a full answer

Comment: OK - so after recording this stream of audio + small amount of text, this still comes down to how to extract the *audio*, right?  I think streaming it to disk is not the solution.  The solution is to be had is by recording the right [`DataLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/capturing.html) while it plays, using Java Sound.  I added the [tag:javasound] tag.